# what does this mean? !function()

Tags: javascript

What does this mean?

```
!function a(){
}({
x: [function(){alert(2);}]
})
```

When I reading some codes in a chrome extension, I have found this block of code. I am confused how this should work.

Comment: The linked duplicate explains the `!function() {}()` part. Regarding the `{ x: [function(){alert(2);}] }` part, that creates an object with a property that is an array containing one element that is a function, but then the function `a()` has an empty body so it doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 2):

It's just another way of writing an IIFE, using a `!` operator instead of parentheses. There are a variety of operators that can be used this way:

```js
! function(text) {
  console.log(text);
}('hello');
```